# RDP Stuck using powershell script / errored out

Tags: powershell

$Cred1 = New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList "domain\user",(ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'password' -AsPlainText -Force);

$servers= Get-Content "C:\Packages\Values.txt"

Function Connect-Mstsc {

```
[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess,DefaultParametersetName='UserPassword')]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=0)]
    [Alias('CN')]
        [string[]]     $ComputerName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='UserPassword',Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [Alias('U')] 
        [string]       $User,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='UserPassword',Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [Alias('P')] 
        [string]       $Password,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Credential',Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [Alias('C')]
        [PSCredential] $Credential,
    [Alias('A')]
        [switch]       $Admin,
    [Alias('MM')]
        [switch]       $MultiMon,
    [Alias('F')]
        [switch]       $FullScreen,
    [Alias('Pu')]
        [switch]       $Public,
    [Alias('W')]
        [int]          $Width,
    [Alias('H')]
        [int]          $Height,
    [Alias('WT')]
        [switch]       $Wait
)

begin {
    [string]$MstscArguments = ''
    switch ($true) {
        {$Admin}      {$MstscArguments += '/admin '}
        {$MultiMon}   {$MstscArguments += '/multimon '}
        {$FullScreen} {$MstscArguments += '/f '}
        {$Public}     {$MstscArguments += '/public '}
        {$Width}      {$MstscArguments += "/w:$Width "}
        {$Height}     {$MstscArguments += "/h:$Height "}
    }

    if ($Credential) {
        $User     = $Credential.UserName
        $Password = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
    }
}
process {
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        $ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        $Process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process

        # Remove the port number for CmdKey otherwise credentials are not entered correctly
        if ($Computer.Contains(':')) {
            $ComputerCmdkey = ($Computer -split ':')[0]
        } else {
            $ComputerCmdkey = $Computer
        }

        $ProcessInfo.FileName    = "$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\cmdkey.exe"
        $ProcessInfo.Arguments   = "/generic:TERMSRV/$ComputerCmdkey /user:$User /pass:$($Password)"
        $ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Hidden
        $Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerCmdkey,'Adding credentials to store')) {
            [void]$Process.Start()
        }

        $ProcessInfo.FileName    = "$($env:SystemRoot)\system32\mstsc.exe"
        $ProcessInfo.Arguments   = "$MstscArguments /v $Computer"
        $ProcessInfo.WindowStyle = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle]::Normal
        $Process.StartInfo       = $ProcessInfo
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($Computer,'Connecting mstsc')) {
            [void]$Process.Start()
            if ($Wait) {
                $null = $Process.WaitForExit()
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

}

### RDP Connection Powershell

foreach ($server in $servers)
{

Need to check any firewall blockings communication between servers

restart-computer $server -Credential $cred1 -Force -ErrorAction Stop
Start-Sleep 20
write-host "Server $server has been initiated with reboot" -BackgroundColor yellow

do {
  $LastSuccess = $true
  Try {
    if (New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList $server,3389 )
    {
       Write-Host $server 'Ready for RDP connection'-ForegroundColor Green

```
}
```

}
  catch { 
    write-warning $error[0]
    start-sleep 30
    $LastSuccess = $false
  }
} until ( $LastSuccess )

Below needs to enabled in source machine to communicate

$server1=$server.tostring()

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $server1 -Force

Invoke-command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred1 -scriptblock{

Enable-PSRemoting  -Force}

connect-mstsc -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred1

## connect-mstsc -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred1  -ErrorAction stop

start-sleep 10

Logoff my session which i logged in

$scriptBlock = {
     $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

```
 try {
     ## Find all sessions matching the specified username
     $sessions = quser | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Testing'}
     ## Parse the session IDs from the output
     $sessionIds = ($sessions -split ' +')[2]
     Write-Host "Found $(@($sessionIds).Count) user login(s) on computer."
     ## Loop through each session ID and pass each to the logoff command
     $sessionIds | ForEach-Object {
         Write-Host "Logging off session id [$($_)]..."
         logoff $_
     }
 } catch {
     if ($_.Exception.Message -match 'No user exists') {
         Write-Host "The user is not logged in."
     } else {
         throw $_.Exception.Message
     }
 }
```

}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $Cred1  -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock

}

Experts .i have tried the above script based on some requirement which needs to restart machines on input list and login and logoff by establish RDP connection it works fine for some  machine,but it is not working in some cases when.login and logoff sometimes failed with logoff and sometime wait until RDP success we need to click ok based on policy, how to mitigate this any other way .login without interruption....Any help much helpful

Error:

WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config

conditions:

I need to take only RDP session to login and logoff

I use single account for all servers to establish connection

Comment: Have you validated the settings in the error message?

Comment: Yes i have validated and its working for some machines